# Is there a Design Pattern that solve this problem?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

2 (+1) Requirements

1.- The user must be able to add many types of Equipment
2.- When the type of equipment is "SOME VALUE" then ...
N.- ... future requirement ... now when the type of equipment is "SOME OTHER VALUE" then ...

The situation is that in one side, I know that the "Types" could change, but also I know that some values must exist particular values of "Type" in order to perform particular behaviors.

```
private int SomeAction(Equipment e)
{
    if (e.Type == "SOME VALUE")
    {
        // Do something for that special case
    }
    else if (e.Type == "SOME OTHER VALUE")
    {
        // Do something for that other special case
    }
    else
    {
        // Do the other thing
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends on the business logic. If you can place that "special case logic" inside the equipment itself, you wont need those chained ifs. 
If you explain more about the domain it would be easy to help you

Comment: thank you from Chile NicoGranelli
The domain is about parts of mechanical equipment, which have "types" that can be created by users, example: type of part: "wheel", "door", "lock". 
Then behaviors are required to occur for some types of parts in particular: "in the case of a door, then perform this or that action"

Comment: Hi manolo!
Assuming  you can't move that logic into the equipment class, I have 2 ideas:
1) if the logic is triggered from outside, the visitor pattern could be usefull. The visitor will know each equipment type and the logic associated. It isn't a great solution, but sometimes you have to accept that
2) if the logic is triggered one equipment at the time, I will try with events and an event dispatcher. The logic will reside in the event handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to put the logic into the `Equipment` class as suggested by @NicoGranelli in the above comment. This is a good approach especially if you have different subclasses of `Equipment`

Another alternative is factor out an `Action` interface. You would have different `Action` implementations and map each equipment type to a specific action. With this approach you eliminate the conditionals. It also facilitates unit testing of each `Action` implementation.

```java
    interface EquipmentAction { void perform(); }

    class SomeAction implements EquipmentAction { void perform() { ... } }
    class SomeOtherAction implements EquipmentAction { void perform() { ...  } }
    class DefaultAction implements EquipmentAction { void perform() { ... } }

    class Client {
        private final Map<EquipmentType,EquipmentAction> equipmentActions = buildEquipmentActionMap();
        private final EquipmentAction DEFAULT_ACTION = new DefaultAction();

        private int SomeAction(Equipment equipment) {
            EquipmentAction action = equipmentActions.getOrDefault(equipment.Type, DEFAULT_ACTION);
            action.perform();
        }
    }
```